# Magento 2 Admin All Customers list view pre-filtering

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, customer-group

Probelm:

I need to filter the **customers Array** in

> "Admin Panel -> Customers -> All Customers"

BEFORE the list is rendered, by an private attribute. The attribute is already exist.

I have 3 different sales user, those are have access to just their customers. All Customers have an attribute calleds "refer". On the php side, i need to check which user is loged in and filter customers by "refer" and display those.

Can anyone Help me please? I need to know which files I have to overwrite.

Comment: Specify your magento version?

Comment: I use ver 2.1.5

Comment: use filter in retrieve query of get collection of customers, in customer model

Comment: That was also my plan. But since I'am not very familiar with magento 2.1, I need a bit more help.
can you tell me which file I have to overwrite? i guess you meen the files in "vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer"?

Comment: vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer/DataProvider.php -> getData()? should I modify this function?

Comment: Any ideas? how to filter the customers list before rendering?

Comment: Any solution? Same problem here.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135205)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135205)

Answer (score 0):

The Grid itself is an UI component and is stored in the Magento file /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml.

There, it is configured to using the collection **Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider** via data source named **customer_listing_data_source**.

To customize it as per your requirement, you may follow steps below :

Assume you are using a custom extension named "**Company_MyModule**".

Also, Assume the customer attribute you mention (i.e "**refer**") is contain admin user_id or user_mail of an admin user

**step 1)**

Create a **di.xml** under ***app/code/Company/MyModule/adminhtml/di.xml***

File: /app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customer_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Company\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

**step 2)** Create the class **Collection.php** under  ***/app/code/Company/MyModule/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Grid/***

File : /app/code/Company/MyModule/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Grid/Collection.php

```
<?php
    namespace Company\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Grid;

    use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;

    use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;

    use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;




    class Collection extends OriginalCollection
    {
        protected $_authSession;
        protected $logger;

        public function __construct(
           EntityFactory $entityFactory,
           Logger $logger,
           FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
           EventManager $eventManager,
           \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
          )
        {        
           $this->_authSession = $authSession;
           $this->logger = $logger;
           parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager);
        }

        protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
            $user = $this->_authSession->getUser();
            $loggedUserId =  $user->getId();
            $this->getSelect()->where('refer='.$loggedUserId);
            parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
        }
    }
?>
```

**step 3:** we need to instruct the grid to display our new column.
create  **file customer_listing.xml** under ***app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/***

File : app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
 <columns name="customer_columns">
 <column name="refer">
 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
 <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Refer</item>
 </item>
 </argument>
 </column>
 </columns>
</listing>
```

**step 4:** Run Following commands

sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: How can I get the query param of this?

Comment: you may inject Request Object in constructor and use $this->request->getParam(PARAM_NAME) to get query Params from URL

Answer (score 0):

@Pritam Info 24 I am getting below error while di:compile

[image]

In exception.log

[image]

**My code in Collection.php**

/var/www/html/ecommerce/app/code/Nimbark/SalesTeam/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Grid/Collection.php

```
    <?php

namespace Nimbark\SalesTeam\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Grid;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends OriginalCollection
    {
        protected $_authSession;
        protected $logger;

        public function __construct(
           EntityFactory $entityFactory,
           Logger $logger,
           FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
           EventManager $eventManager,
           \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
          )
        {        
           $this->_authSession = $authSession;
           $this->logger = $logger;
           parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager);
        }

        protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
            $user = $this->_authSession->getUser();
            $loggedUserId =  $user->getId();
            $this->getSelect()->where('salesman_id='.$loggedUserId);
            parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
        }
    }
?>
```

**Code in di.xml**

/var/www/html/ecommerce/app/code/Nimbark/SalesTeam/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customer_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Nimbark\SalesTeam\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```